# Laravel: addressing first item from array in view file

Tags: laravel

Staring blind at something simple:

I have events model which contains multiple images. In the view, I only want to post the first image. I'm currently doing the following:

```
@foreach( $events as $event )
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            @foreach( $event->images as $key => $image  )
               @if ($key == 0)
                 <img src="{{ $image->filename }}" class="img-responsive" />
               @endif
            @endforeach
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

However, I think there must be easier ways, something in the lines of:

```
@foreach( $events as $event )
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
         <div class="panel-heading">
             <img src="{{ $event->images(){0}->filename }}" class="img-responsive" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

This results in *Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany as array*.

Any ideas how to do this?

### Additional information

Controller code is:

```
public function index() {
    $events = Event::currentEvents()->get();
    return view('guest/events/index', ['events' => $events]);
}
```

Model is:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    public function scopeCurrentEvents($query) {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        return $query->where('event_startdate', '<=', $now)
             ->where('event_closedate', '>=', $now);
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Image', 'imageable');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<img src="{{ $event->images()->first()->filename }}" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: This results in 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: I would check dd($event), and if there are no images in relations I would check if relation is correctly described inside models. Or maybe one event has no image - than you should check with if - if image exists.

Comment: Can you do dd($event) in the view file. Also: pretty sure the relations are OK as the first example (see my original question) is working.

Comment: I do dd inside view (it's a helper). Does your every event has image? If there is no image for event, there will be error.

Comment: dd in the view does not seem to work. Every event must have an image. I will check that elsewhere. And if not, I will display a placeholder picture. The code given does not have this build in yet, but it will be added later

Comment: so inspect dd($events) inside controller

Comment: 100% sure there are images. The first codeblock in the original question shows them.

Comment: check dd, maybe images are returned as collection not relation objects, also check Image model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<img src="{{ $event[0]->images()->filename }}" class="img-responsive" />
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This results in Call to a member function images() on null

Comment: I added it to the original question. Note that the first code block in my question is working fine.